# .vimrc file configuration: cursor looks the same whether or not in insert mode

Tags: vim

Upon a quick read through the `.vimrc` file I grabbed [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Example_vimrc#Example_vimrc), I can't find the line that is making the cursor appear the same in both insert and non-insert mode.  Please point out to me the line(s) that is(are) making this occur.

**Update (6.10.13)**:  I'm using Fedora 17 and xTerm.

Comment: FYI only, I just copied the .vimrc from the link and gvim and vim displayed the cursor differently for normal and insert modes.  Are you using vim or gvim?  Are you on Linux/Windows/Mac?

Comment: hmm...odd.  My cursor displayed differently respective of the mode I was in before, but not after I uploaded the .vimrc file.  It looks like I'm using Vim 7.2, and I'm definitely on linux.

Comment: I was using vim 7.0 on Linux (Redhat flavor).

Comment: I take it my answer didn't help?

Comment: @nickecarlo , I was able to get the cursor to change to an orange color, via the guide link you gave me, but I'm unable to get it to the bar in insert mode using the code for xTerm on the guide page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Gnome terminal, you can use the following commands to change the cursor as per your needs:

```
au InsertEnter * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape ibeam"    
au InsertLeave * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape block"
```

The above will set your cursor to a bar when you enter insert mode and change it to a block when you exit it.

If you have some other terminal, check this guide here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor

NOTE: The example .vimrc file does not seem to be doing anything to your cursor other than displaying its position.

Comment: Note that `InsertLeave` event will not be called if you use `<c-c>` instead of `<esc>`/`<c-[>`

Comment: I'm using xTerm, and I think that not having the straight bar in insert mode may be the default for this terminal, because after removing the .vimrc file, I still don't have it.  I'm used to using vim in other terminals, and this happens to be my first time running [Fedora 17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_(operating_system)#Version_history)

Comment: @beProactive Can you tell me what Desktop you're running on your Fedora? I can successfully change the shape of the cursor on my Fedora 17. Note though that I launch xterm by executing 'xterm' in the LXTerminal (the default terminal emulator that comes with LXDE Desktop) and the necessary commands for xterm in my vimrc work flawlessly. If you can tell me what Desktop you're using or what file you downloaded from Fedora to install the OS, I can then help you out more exactly.